# Steady state of dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems

I have the following dynamical system:
$$
f\left(x_{t},y_{t},z_{t}\right)=g\left(x_{t+1},y_{t+1},z_{t+1};\alpha\right)
$$
where $x_{t},y_{t}$ and $z_{t}$ are dynamic variables indexed by
time. The two time periods are linked by this parameter $\alpha.$
To find the steady state, I essentially drop the $t$ subscript, as
$x_{t}=x_{t+1}$ for instance, and then solve for the value of $\alpha$
such that:
$$
f(x,y,z)=g\left(z,y,z;\alpha\right)
$$
By doing this, I have assumed first that the variables are unchanging,
and what that implies for the parameter value $\alpha.$ However,
does this go the other way? In other words, is it also true that for
this value of $\alpha$ , $x,y$ and $z$ is unchanging?

Comment: Are $f,g$ scalar or vector-valued functions?

Comment: Scalar functions.

Comment: Then all this says is that the next point lies on some hypersurface in 3-space. There is not enough information to get unique values for all 3 variables.